# sublime text 2 how to set environment variable

Tags: text-editor, sublimetext2, ubuntu-12.04

i want set Environment variables.

that says https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html

> Snippet Features Environment Variables Snippets have access to
> contextual information in the form of environment variables. Sublime
> Text sets the values of the variables listed below automatically.
>
> You can also add your own variables to provide extra information.
> These custom variables are defined in .sublime-options files.

but i cant found .sublime-options file.

i want set the $TM_FILENAME and $TM_FULLNAME variables.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This thread may help: http://www.sublimetext.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=3852 .
I test it on my macbook and works for me.

Comment: Works for me in 2015 on Sublime Text 3 (ST3) on windows.