# Sublime Text 2 - `Mandrill::Error: You must provide a Mandrill API key`

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec, sublimetext2, mandrill

I am using Sublime Text 2 as my editor for rails applications and have an rspec test suite which passed without issue until I added email functionality using the Mandrill API.

Wherever I now attempt to send an email I receive the following error:

```
Mandrill::Error:
       You must provide a Mandrill API key
```

If I run these tests within the terminal, they pass.

The API key is set as an environment variable within my `.bash_profile`.

Is there a way to configure Sublime Text to use these variables?

Comment: What OS are you using, and how are you running your test within Sublime? If it's a plugin, please provide the URL.

Comment: @MattDMo I am using Mac OSX 10.9.4. Using RubyTest: https://github.com/maltize/sublime-text-2-ruby-tests. Also using Zeus https://github.com/burke/zeus

Comment: It sounds like the test suite isn't being invoked with the environment variables defined in your `.bash_profile`. This is often caused by a process being started in a non-login shell. What does the plugin print if you add `puts ENV; exit` at the top of your test suite? Also, try changing the command the plugin is running to `source ~/.bash_profile && {original command}` (without the curly braces)

Comment: Thanks @Matt. Interestingly if I put puts ENV.inspect;exit at the start none of the environment variables are shown. If I put a breakpoint in (binding.pry) and try, they are all listed. As an aside my Facebook keys (set in .bash_profile) do work correctly when running within rubytest. I'm not quite sure where to include `source ...`, but have tried within the rubytest.sublime-settings changing to: `"run_rspec_command": "source ~/.bash_profile && rspec {relative_path}"`, but this gives an error on running of `ruby: No such file or directory -- source (LoadError)`

Comment: Interestingly though... Just spotted in that last comment that the zeus command is missing, so I wasn't using zeus after all. If I change the run command to `"run_rspec_command": "zeus rspec {relative_path}"` the environment is set within zeus (I assume) and the test runs correctly. I think that answers the question. @Matt if you have anything useful to add re the addition of `source ...` then please do, but you are welcome to provide and answer to collect the bounty.

Comment: You should answer your own question and accept it.

Comment: You should not configure API key in bash_profile since it's not in ruby/rails environment. Instead put in some dotfiles as an environment variable to be read in rails environment . (Correct me if i am wrong).

Answer (score 0):

try this out:

I think you are looking for how to set environment variables in sublime text?

so there is a solution already on stackoverflow.

[sublime text how to set environment variable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12901537/sublime-text-2-how-to-set-environment-variable)

Comment: Forgive me if I am incorrect, but this appears to be for setting variables for use within Sublime Text, not by the application.

Answer (score 0):

The **Sublime Text** architecture is quite nice and allows you to implement your own *plugin* easily.

They are automatically loaded when Sublime Text starts. Thus you can write your own custom plugin that sets these variables in the Sublime text *env*:

```
# ~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages/User/your_plugin.py
import os

os.environ['MANDRIL_API_PUBLIC'] = 'xxxxx'
os.environ['MANDRIL_API_PRIVATE'] = 'xxxxx'
```

Have a look [here](http://robdodson.me/blog/2012/05/14/hacking-the-path-variable-in-sublime-text/) for more informations.